# Apache poi PowerPoint slide masters - not generating footer with page number

Tags: java, apache-poi, powerpoint, slideshow, slide

I have problem with slide master layout which contains page number and static text. I have them on my layouts but they are not appearing once I'm generating presentation. When I go INSTER --> Page Number I can select and they appear. When I'm adding new slide to my generated presentation via PowerPoint (add slide with selected layout), then it's showing page number for that page.
Here is the code:

```
String fileName = "slidemaster-010";
            String templateLocation = "/Users/akonopko/Export/Templates/Presentation10.pptx";
            XMLSlideShow ppt = new XMLSlideShow(new FileInputStream(templateLocation));

            XSLFSlideMaster defaultMaster = ppt.getSlideMasters().get(0);

            XSLFSlideLayout masterLayout = defaultMaster.getLayout("Master");
            XSLFSlide slide = ppt.createSlide(masterLayout);

            XSLFSlideLayout masterLayout1 = defaultMaster.getLayout("1_Custom Layout");
            XSLFSlide slide2 = ppt.createSlide(masterLayout1);

            List<XSLFShape> slideShapes = slide2.getShapes();
            for (XSLFShape shape : slideShapes) {
                if (shape.getPlaceholder() == Placeholder.TITLE) {
                    ((XSLFTextShape) shape).setText("Test Text");
                }
            }
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Apache POI just does not copy the placeholders from the `XSLFSlideLayout` while `XMLSlideShow.createSlide(XSLFSlideLayout)`. It uses [XSLFSlideLayout.copyLayout(XSLFSlide)](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_5_2_2/poi-ooxml/src/main/java/org/apache/poi/xslf/usermodel/XSLFSlideLayout.java?view=markup#l116) and there `SLIDE_NUMBER` is explicitly excluded.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you help how to make it available?

Comment: @AxelRichter Do you know how to make this objects available? is there any setting that can do that? Right now I'm able to make it visible via CTShape but one of my object in footer is a link that I'd like to change. In XML of that object I don't see URL.

Answer (score 0):

Apache POI just does not copy the placeholders from the `XSLFSlideLayout` while `XMLSlideShow.createSlide(XSLFSlideLayout)`. It uses [XSLFSlideLayout.copyLayout(XSLFSlide)](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_5_2_2/poi-ooxml/src/main/java/org/apache/poi/xslf/usermodel/XSLFSlideLayout.java?view=markup#l116) and there `DATETIME`, `SLIDE_NUMBER` and `FOOTER` is explicitly excluded.

One could write a method which copies those placeholders from the layout. This could look like so:

```
 public void copyPlaceholdersFromLayout(XSLFSlideLayout layout, XSLFSlide slide) {
  for (XSLFShape sh : layout.getShapes()) {
   if (sh instanceof XSLFTextShape) {
    XSLFTextShape tsh = (XSLFTextShape) sh;
    Placeholder ph = tsh.getTextType();
    if (ph == null) continue;
    switch (ph) {
     // these are special and not copied by default
     case DATETIME:
     case SLIDE_NUMBER:
     case FOOTER:
      System.out.println(ph);
      slide.getXmlObject().getCSld().getSpTree().addNewSp().set(tsh.getXmlObject().copy());
      break;
     default:
      //slide.getSpTree().addNewSp().set(tsh.getXmlObject().copy());
      //already done
    }
   }
  }
 }
```

Get called like so:

```
copyPlaceholdersFromLayout(masterLayout1, slide2);
```

But there might be a reason why `apache poi` explicitly excludes this.